# How to add an event or function in JavaScript to an HTML collection?

Tags: html, getelementbyid, htmlcollection

I have the following JavaScript , where I get an HTML element(grid) and the HTML element children (photos inside the grid).

```
let Galeria = document.getElementById("CaixaGaleria");
let GaleriaPhoto = document.getElementById("CaixaGaleria").children;
```

This is the HTML :

```
 <div id ="CaixaGaleria" class="gallery">
    <div data-tecnica="lapis" data-estilo="retrato" data-tamanho="pequeno"><img src="Imagens/Filme/14.jpg"></div>
    <div data-tecnica="lapis" data-estilo="retrato" data-tamanho="medio"><img src="Imagens/Filme/16.jpg"></div>
    <div data-tecnica="lapis" data-estilo="retrato" data-tamanho="grande"><img src="Imagens/Filme/17.jpg"></div>
    <div data-tecnica="aguarela" data-estilo="paisagem" data-tamanho="pequeno"><img src="Imagens/Filme/20.jpg"></div>
    <div data-tecnica="aguarela" data-estilo="paisagem" data-tamanho="medio"><img src="Imagens/Filme/22.jpg"></div>
    <div data-tecnica="aguarela" data-estilo="paisagem" data-tamanho="grande"><img src="Imagens/Filme/27.jpg"></div>
    <div data-tecnica="oleo" data-estilo="ilustração" data-tamanho="pequeno"><img src="Imagens/Filme/37.jpg"></div>
    <div data-tecnica="oleo" data-estilo="ilustração" data-tamanho="medio"><img src="Imagens/Filme/42.jpg"></div>
    <div data-tecnica="oleo" data-estilo="ilustração" data-tamanho="grande"><img src="Imagens/Filme/53.jpg"></div>
  </div>
```

My goal is to add an EventListener to the children , so that when I click on them the image is displayed on it's original size and ratio , something like this :

```
GaleriaPhoto.addEventListener("click" , function(){
    *this function should display image's original size on a new window or popup*
 }
  );
```

However , I can't add an EventListener to this element nor a ForEach() or push().

I will always get some error like "TypeError: GaleriaPhoto.addEventListener is not a function".

I can do it , to the 1st variable but not the second one ,  so I assume the problem is something related to the fact that it is an HTML colection ?

Comment: This is because it's iterating all child nodes, including text nodes etc, which will not have the function `addEventListener`. Simply check that the node is the correct type or check the function exists beforehand.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] including html? Also consider adding the EventListener to CaixaGaleria and utilising [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to get the child element clicked

Comment: Hi , thanks for the help. Does that mean I have to delete the text inside the div ?

Comment: Disregard my earlier comment, I was getting mixed up with `.childNodes`, not `.children`. In this case, you simply need to iterate over each node to apply the event listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over each child node and apply the event listener, `.children` returns a collect type called HTMLCollection (which does not have a `.addEventListener` function), not a html node itself (which does). But you can iterate over it like a normal array.

So something like

```
<div id ="CaixaGaleria" class="gallery">
  <div data-tecnica="lapis" data-estilo="retrato" data-tamanho="pequeno"><img src="Imagens/Filme/14.jpg"></div>
  <div data-tecnica="lapis" data-estilo="retrato" data-tamanho="medio"><img src="Imagens/Filme/16.jpg"></div>
  <div data-tecnica="lapis" data-estilo="retrato" data-tamanho="grande"><img src="Imagens/Filme/17.jpg"></div>
  <div data-tecnica="aguarela" data-estilo="paisagem" data-tamanho="pequeno"><img src="Imagens/Filme/20.jpg"></div>
  <div data-tecnica="aguarela" data-estilo="paisagem" data-tamanho="medio"><img src="Imagens/Filme/22.jpg"></div>
  <div data-tecnica="aguarela" data-estilo="paisagem" data-tamanho="grande"><img src="Imagens/Filme/27.jpg"></div>
  <div data-tecnica="oleo" data-estilo="ilustração" data-tamanho="pequeno"><img src="Imagens/Filme/37.jpg"></div>
  <div data-tecnica="oleo" data-estilo="ilustração" data-tamanho="medio"><img src="Imagens/Filme/42.jpg"></div>
  <div data-tecnica="oleo" data-estilo="ilustração" data-tamanho="grande"><img src="Imagens/Filme/53.jpg"></div>
</div>
<script>
  let Galeria = document.getElementById("CaixaGaleria");
  let GaleriaPhotos = document.getElementById("CaixaGaleria").children;
  for(let x = 0; x < GaleriaPhotos.length; x++) {
    GaleriaPhotos[x].addEventListener("click" , function(){
        alert("blah");
      }
    );
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks man !! I tried to do this using ForEach() on the GaleriaPhoto but it didn't work xD lol

Comment: No problem :) That is because even though you can access indexes like an array (`collection[x]`) it actually isn't an array, it's a HTMLCollection, so useful methods like .forEach aren't defined for it (See more here -> https://www.gavsblog.com/blog/htmlcollection-foreach-loop-convert-object-to-array-javascript)

Comment: It could also be a Node List, which is again array-like, without actually being an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add an event listener to the gallery then use `event.target` to get information from the element clicked. This has the advantage of handling dynamically added elements without having to rebind event listeners.

Note, in this example the target is actually the images, not the divs.

```js
let gallery  = document.getElementById("CaixaGaleria");
gallery.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  console.log(event.target);
  //Your logic to display image here
  //Demo
  alert("src = " +event.target.src);
})
```

```html
<div id="CaixaGaleria" class="gallery">
  <div data-tecnica="lapis" data-estilo="retrato" data-tamanho="pequeno"><img src="Imagens/Filme/14.jpg"></div>
  <div data-tecnica="lapis" data-estilo="retrato" data-tamanho="medio"><img src="Imagens/Filme/16.jpg"></div>
  <div data-tecnica="lapis" data-estilo="retrato" data-tamanho="grande"><img src="Imagens/Filme/17.jpg"></div>
  <div data-tecnica="aguarela" data-estilo="paisagem" data-tamanho="pequeno"><img src="Imagens/Filme/20.jpg"></div>
  <div data-tecnica="aguarela" data-estilo="paisagem" data-tamanho="medio"><img src="Imagens/Filme/22.jpg"></div>
  <div data-tecnica="aguarela" data-estilo="paisagem" data-tamanho="grande"><img src="Imagens/Filme/27.jpg"></div>
  <div data-tecnica="oleo" data-estilo="ilustração" data-tamanho="pequeno"><img src="Imagens/Filme/37.jpg"></div>
  <div data-tecnica="oleo" data-estilo="ilustração" data-tamanho="medio"><img src="Imagens/Filme/42.jpg"></div>
  <div data-tecnica="oleo" data-estilo="ilustração" data-tamanho="grande"><img src="Imagens/Filme/53.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks , that's actually very helpfull for what I am trying to do!! =D

Answer (score 0):

Add click event to every children and call same handler with different parameter. like this,

```
<html>
 <div class="gallery">
    <div onclick="handleClick('Imagens/Filme/14.jpg')" data-tecnica="lapis" data-estilo="retrato" data-tamanho="pequeno"><img src="Imagens/Filme/14.jpg"></div>

  </div>
</html>

<script>
 function handleClick(url){
    // handle url
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Do not do this. Inline event handlers are considered bad practice these days. There a **many** better options